# How to add a variable to another variable that's already set

Tags: java

My homework is to create a program that takes a list of numbers and prints out the highest number divisible by four.

List would look like this:

```
12  
16  
87  
58  
25  
73  
86  
36  
79  
40  
12  
89  
32
```

Input should be:
40 because it is the highest number there divisible by four.

Here is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int saved = 0;
        int saved2 = 0;

        for (int i = scanner.nextInt(); i % 4 == 0; i = scanner.nextInt()) {
            for (boolean bull = true; bull == true; bull ^= true) {
                if (i > saved) {
                    saved -= saved2;
                    saved += i;
                    saved2 += i;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(saved);
        }
    }
}
```

The input of my code is

```
12  
16
```

I don't really understand why this is doing it, but it seems to me that I'm adding the variables wrong. The homework page on adding variables does not specify how to add variables to each other.
Does anyone have a tip to improve the code in anyway, or find a way to make a fix my code? Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: Are you confusing input and output? The list is your input, what you describe as input seems to be output to me.

Comment: Please explain your thinking behind those interesting for-loop constructs. That is part of https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your indentation seems misleading. With some changes for consistency, it at least becomes clearer why youmore than one outputs.

Comment: `for (boolean bull = true; bull == true; bull ^= true)` This looks really strange. What is the meaning of this line? Do you expect `bull` variable to change?

Comment: The program is taking a list and giving an output divisible by four. That's your question  @Fran____

Comment: Seems like I did confuse input and output, my bad. Also, for the bull variable, I see it was extremely flawed and I have no idea what I was thinking. I'll be making sense of the answers right now.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Java.

First you are saying you got input, but that is output. Input is what you enter, and output is what you get printed.

Then there is a mistake in your for loops. You have too much going on in one place. By the logic which is implemented, your program will exit first level for loop whenever your entered value is not divisable by 4.

Read on for loops if you want to learn more https://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Loops.

I recommend to start from `while` loops instead. The logic whould be this:

1. create variable to hold the correct answer `saved`

2. create another one to hold the value read from console `i`

3. start the `while` loop with condition `i = scanner.nextInt()`

3.1 check if the value just entered `i` is divisable by 4

3.2 if it is, then compare if it's larger than the one was saved before (initially `saved` value will be 0)

3.3 if it is larger, then assign the read value `i` to the `saved`

4. At the end of the loop, you will have the highest number divisable by four in your `saved` variable. Print it.

Comment: Also a nice way to answer helpfully without just giving the solution to a homework question.

Comment: thank you! I will research the while loop more. The explanation gave me little about while loops and more about for loops so I wasn't sure if we were supposed to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide some help, according to
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

```
for (int i = scanner.nextInt(); i % 4 == 0;i = scanner.nextInt())
```

This only reads as long as ALL inputs are divisible by 4, that is why it ends at 16, because 87 is not divisible by 4.

```
for (boolean bull = true; bull == true ;bull ^= true)
```

This needs explanation by you, but I am pretty sure that it unconditionally executes the body of the inner loop exactly once. (Not 100% sure, because the representation of `true` and `false` could be weird in your machine. Should 0 be the representation of `true`, i.e. really weird, then it is an endless loop, which does not match the output you describe...)

```
System.out.println(saved);
```

This executes exactly once per input, except the last one, which is not a multiple of 4.

The value of `saved` is identical to input, as long as it is increasing.

These hints explain the unexpected output.
If you inspect the details of what the problem is, you should be able to improve your coding attempt.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I super-quickly fixed in your code.
Note that there are no statements about the possible minimum value and about how do you stop the input. Therefore the solution is pretty-straightforward, it just reads the input until integers are present there.

[This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-nextint-method-in-java-with-examples/) may be useful about handling the input from the `Scanner`.

I hope the comments in the code will help. Add comments if there are any questions. Good luck!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int currentMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // you may set negative or 0 if you know that all the input is positive
//      int saved2 = 0; // no need for this variable

        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) { // you can make a better input handling, especially if you know when it should end the input. Now it will end on any non-integer input line
            int i = scanner.nextInt();

            //      for (int i = scanner.nextInt(); i % 4 == 0; i = scanner.nextInt()) {
//          for (boolean bull = true; bull == true; bull ^= true) {
                if (((i % 4) == 0) && (i > currentMax)) {
                    currentMax = i;
//                  saved -= saved2;
//                  saved += i;
//                  saved2 += i;
//              }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(currentMax); // moved out of "for" or "while" cycles. Print the value after the input has ended.
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the discussion in the link I provided in my answer? You seem to ignore the proposed compromise.

Comment: Helpful but I wasn't looking for a solution really. Helps a lot though!